# Configure datadog agent to avoid kube-proxy logs

Tags: logging, datadog, kube-proxy

I am having lots of info logs from `kube-proxy` in Datadog and for now I would like to avoid that.
The kind of logs I am having looks like the following:
[image]

I have [disabled payload](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/guide/how-to-set-up-only-logs/?tab=kubernetes) expecting it would help, but with no luck.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [the `DD_CONTAINER_EXCLUDE_LOGS` env var could come in handy](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/kubernetes/?tab=helm#ignore-containers)?

If not, maybe you can share a bit more info on how you configure log collection today? More context of your setup (if you can share it) might help dig up better suggestions.

Comment: thanks @stephenlechner. Will take a look at it